# Is there a term for a button or feature that does not actually do anything, other than giving the user a sense of control?

Tags: etymology, neologisms, technology

I was wondering if there was a one-word term for this. I suppose a classic example might be the "Door Close" button on an elevator. Essentially, a working feature that apparently does something, and the user can activate it but it will not actually play any meaningful role in the operation of the device.

Comment: I'd guess that the UX designers have a term for it.

Comment: An appendage or a placebo? I believe the Door Close button does not close it but does signal the elevator's computer that it could close it when ready, rather than hold it open for some previous event.

Comment: Placebo is the word I was thinking of, too. It exists to appease the user, but doesn't actually do anything directly.

Comment: "Placebo" was the consensus term when I posed this question to somewhat less literary-minded people. I really wasn't happy with it as it has such a medicinal connotation and this is more of an engineering/UX sense. But I appreciate your input immensely perhaps "placebo" is the best term.

Comment: This really makes me think of the [superstitious pigeons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._F._Skinner#%22'Superstition'_in_the_Pigeon%22_experiment) experiment  [which can apply to humans too;)

Comment: The *placebo button* is also called the *idiot button* or *dummy button* in UX. I call it the *busy button* to be polite.

Comment: *nullipotent* action

Answer (score 2):

Those are called **placebo buttons.** [As Wikipedia explains:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo_button)

> A placebo button is a push-button or other control that appears to have functionality but has no physical effect when pressed. Such buttons can appear to work, by lighting up or otherwise reacting, which rewards the user by giving them an illusion of control. They are commonly placed in situations where it would have once been useful to have such a button but the system now operates automatically, such as a manual thermostat in a temperature-regulated office. Were the control removed entirely, some users would feel frustrated at the awareness they were not in control.

Comment: While the customs of this site allow 'upgrading' an answer that originally  appeared in a comment (or, as in this case, comments) to a formal answer, one should acknowledge within the answer that this is what one is doing.

Comment: @jsw29 I actually hadn't read the comments before posting this; it's a pure coincidence if the term was also mentioned there.